# How to call multiple services via a single service in Talend?

Tags: esb, talend

I am new to Talend ESB. I have a ReST service A which creates a record in Table A. There is also a SOAP Service called B which creates a record in table B. I need to create a ReST service which can call both service A and service B so there is a single ESB layer to access both the services. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a REST Service through the 'job' interface, as you would normally do to create a job. Make sure to use tRESTRequest as your input.
Inside your REST Service, you can make calls to existing SOAP / REST service through the dedicated components : tESBConsumer & tRESTClient.